# How to keep the unit test output in Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, stdout, jenkins

We have managed to have Jenkins correctly parse our XML output from our tests and also included the error information, when there is one. So that it is possible to see, directly in the TestCase in Jenkins the error that occurred.

What we would like to do is to have Jenkins keep a log output, which is basically the console output, associated with each case. This would enable anyone to see the actual console output of each test case, failed or not.

I haven't seen a way to do this.

*** EDIT ***

Clarification - I want to be able to see the actual test output directly in the Jenkins interface, the same way it does when there is an error, but for the whole output. I don't want only Jenkins to keep the file as artifact.

*** END OF EDIT ***

Anyone can help us on this?

Answer (score 8):

In the **Publish JUnit test result report** (Post-build Actions) tick the `Retain long standard output/error` checkbox.

> If checked, any standard output or error from a test suite will be
>   retained in the test results after the build completes. (This refers
>   only to additional messages printed to console, not to a failure stack
>   trace.) Such output is always kept if the test failed, but by default
>   lengthy output from passing tests is truncated to save space. Check
>   this option if you need to see every log message from even passing
>   tests, but beware that Jenkins's memory consumption can substantially
>   increase as a result, even if you never look at the test results!

[image]

Comment: Can't find that option in `Jenkins ver. 2.222.4` :(

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do - just ensure that the output file is included in the list of artifacts for that job and it will be archived according to the configuration for that job.

Comment: I want to be able to see the actual test output directly in the Jenkins interface, the same way it does when there is an error, but for the whole output. I don't want only Jenkins to keep the file as artifact.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solve it yet, but I just did something similar using Android and Jenkins.

What I did was using the http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/ to run the tests in the Android emulator. This will create the necessary JUnit formatted XML files, on the emulator file system.

Afterwards, simply use 'adb pull' to copy the file over, and configure the Jenkin to parse the results. You can also artifact the XML files if necessary.

If you simply want to display the content of the result in the log, you can use 'Execute Shell' command to print it out to the console, where it will be captured in the log file.

Comment: https://github.com/Polidea/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner This repository is no longer maintained. Issue reports and pull requests will not be attended.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins 1.386 there was a change mentioned to Retain long standard output/error in each build configuration. So you just have to check the checkbox in the post-build actions.

http://hudson-ci.org/changelog.html#v1.386

Answer (score 1):

When using a declarative pipeline, you can do it like so:

```
junit testResults: '**/build/test-results/*/*.xml', keepLongStdio: true
```

See [the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/):

> If checked, the default behavior of failing a build on missing test result files or empty test results is changed to not affect the status of the build. Please note that this setting make it harder to spot misconfigured jobs or build failures where the test tool does not exit with an error code when not producing test report files.