# How to write comment from java to Jenkins log?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have test in java that run on Jenkins.

Is it no possible to debug that test and therefore I want to add dummy comment to the java and also to see values of variables 
I want to see it in the console output of the Jenkins ? 
How I can do it ? 
`System.out.println()` did not work for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep the unit test output in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944907/how-to-keep-the-unit-test-output-in-jenkins)

Comment: You're meant to work with Jenkins through its web UI and REST API. As far as I'm aware, the console output is only for operations purposes and doesn't include the output of whatever is being built or tested on Jenkins.

Comment: I want to run java test and to add some comment

Comment: Jenkins stores the output of the build process - including what you output with System.out.println() - in the "builds" subdirectory of your job in [JENKINS_HOME](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins). That's where you have to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a java testing framework like JUnit, then any tests run will be logged by Jenkins, including any print statements that the tests execute.

Jenkins also has a plugin specifically for JUnit [(found here)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin), which will publish the results so you can easily access them in Jenkins, allowing you to see if tests fail, and then inspect anything printed out, as well as the stack trace, for any given test.

Answer (score 0):

If your junit tests are being run by an ant task, then you can simply add a formatter to your task. For example:

```
<target name="unit-tests">
    <junit>
        ...
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

Copied directly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746909/26510)